# Firefox: show bookmarks location in search result

Tags: windows, firefox, search, bookmarks

I've been a user of firefox for years. Like most, I collected a large number of bookmarks, and over time it now contins lots of folders and nested folders...

When I add a new bookmark, I would like to place in specific folder as other related ones. The thing is when I use the search functionality in the Bookmarks Library, it does not say what folder each item is in. And I end up manually looking through all folders (very tedious!)

Any suggestion on how to do more efficiently?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Show Parent Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-parent-folder/) extension allows you to add a column to the library that shows the folder where the bookmark is located.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

firefox has a built-in [Bookmark Tagging](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Bookmark+Tags) system designed to make the process of organising your bookmarks more efficient. Unfortunately, to make best use of this you will likely have to tag your existing bookmarks.

Comment: I am aware of tagging, in fact I use both tags and folders to organize bookmarks.. For those interested, there's a useful extension that suggests relevant tags from sources like delicious: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7498/
I think Xmarks does that as well..